# WHERE greater than a given datetime to reduce queried rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I've got a stored procedure that searches for rows in a table based on a given text. `TableWithText` has a `SomeText` column of type nvarchar and also a `CreateDate` `DateTime` column populated with the date and time that the row was created.

The body of the stored procedure is this:

```
SELECT TableWithTextID, SomeOtherColumn 
FROM TableWithText 
WHERE SomeText = @inputText
```

The value of SomeText for each is guaranteed to be unique although no such constraint is imposed. Therefore this statement is expected to return only one row.

However the table has some 500,000 rows. Given that I know when the row I'm looking for was entered (down to the minute), if I add

```
AND CreateDate >= @CreateDate
```

to the stored procedure, will the MS SQL query optimizer reduce the amount of query rows to those created after @CreateDate before it searches for the input text?

Comment: When you say `reduce the amount of query rows`, are you referring to the result set or the amount of rows that it's searching through to find the row the column value of `@inputText`?

Comment: I'm referring to the amount of rows it's searching through before it finds this one match.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to review the execution plan and see what the optimizer is telling you. You might think there is a problem just by looking at the query and the number of rows but the actual cost is quite low.

If you already have an index on CreateDate, then add this to the where clause and it should take advantage of that.

Otherwise, you would be better off indexing the SomeText field if this is something that is run a lot and you are noticing full table scans when executing this. I'm guessing it's used in other queries two given that it's a unique thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, potentially, but only if you add an index on the CreateDate column (or an index on SomeText, CreateDate)

Comment: Not if there's an index on the `SomeText` column